# Number of processes is maxed out after installing another WordPress add-on site

Tags: wordpress, process

I have a website that works fine, I add a add-on domain and install another wordpress there.
Now, the website says

> Internal Server Error

and does not open both of main domain and add-on domain.

The only dubious thing in cpanel is **Number of Processes** 25/25 -- how I should I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like your site may be busier than your host allows for.

Comment: How can I watch list of process?
How can I Kill unneeded process?

Comment: You can probably get this from the unix shell but i doubt you'll have privileges for killing processes

Comment: The problem was from the hosting, and has solved now.